# Tkinter binding Listbox information to another tinker windows without select bottom

Tags: python, tkinter

I have two windows one is for broadcast and other for controlling information by `listbox`,
how can I pass the listbox data from main windows to another windows label text?

```
class NewWindow(Toplevel):
     
    def __init__(self, master = None):
         
        super().__init__(master = master)
        self.title("New Window")
        self.geometry("200x200")
        label = Label(self, text ="This is a new Window")
        label.pack()

master = Tk()

master.geometry("200x200")
 
label = Label(master, text ="This is the main window")
label.pack(side = TOP, pady = 10)

btn = Button(master,
             text ="Click to open a new window")

btn.bind("<Button>",
         lambda e: NewWindow(master))
 
btn.pack(pady = 10)

listbox = tk.Listbox(master)

listbox.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

listbox.insert("end", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five")

def callback(event):
    selection = event.widget.curselection()
    if selection:
        index = selection[0]
        data = event.widget.get(index)
        label.configure(text=data)
    else:
        label.configure(text="")

listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", callback)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: If I understand this correctly - you want to click an item in the listbox, then click the button to show information on a TopLevel window?

Comment: Yes, and after new windows pop up, I'd like to change the label text by clicking listbox without any addition action. 
e.g. When I click one at first time the label in Toplevel will show one, and after that when I click two, the label in Toplevel will change to two Immediately.

Comment: This code is incomplete for testing. Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a workaround your code. Basically, you want to keep track of the new `TopLevel` window being created. You can do this by using a `global` variable.

This should do the trick:

```
import tkinter as tk


class NewWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master=master)
        self.title("New Window")
        self.geometry("200x200")
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="This is a new Window")
        self.label.pack()


def new_window():
    global window
    window = NewWindow(master)  # only the latest new TopLevel window is tracked


def callback(event):
    global window
    if window:
        selection = event.widget.curselection()
        if selection:
            index = selection[0]
            data = event.widget.get(index)
            window.label.configure(text=data)
        else:
            window.label.configure(text="")


window = None  # The global variable to keep track of your 'latest' TopLevel window
master = tk.Tk()

master.geometry("200x200")

label = tk.Label(master, text="This is the main window")
label.pack(side=TOP, pady=10)

btn = tk.Button(master, text="Click to open a new window", command=new_window)
btn.pack(pady=10)

listbox = tk.Listbox(master)
listbox.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
listbox.insert("end", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
listbox.select_set(0)
listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", callback)

master.mainloop()
```

A few suggestions:

1. Always use - `import tkinter as tk`. Always prefix your tkinter modules.
2. Try to use `class` for the main window

Comment: If you want to keep track of all the new windows that you have created, I would suggest storing the created instances in a list or dict. Depends on how you want to control them

Comment: You can use a class attribute to keep track so you do not have to use global. Always a good idea to avoid using a global.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Yes. I agree. But I just gave the OP an idea on how to code this. It will be way better if the OP can come up with the class structure, all on their own.

Comment: Got it, and this solved my problem, I will use prefix for modules in my future work. Thanks for help!